# Не стандартные ходы в игре на Unity. Как прописать их логику верно?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю проект для самообучения (готовый код не нужен). Не пойму, как построить логику ходов игры верно и как работать с такими ходами. Смотрел шахматы и гексы на гитхабе - это близко, но мне показалось это не подходит.

[Анимашку](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_S0EN6AO2V_jNXuC5JWEniyYILVAeB7G) накидал как это должно быть - тут наглядно видно, что и как. Ну и на картинке видно тоже.
[image]
Игровое поле состоит из кривых линий с точками, по которым может ходить игрок и соперник. Бросаем кубик. Выпало например 5. Мы можем походить на определенное количество клеток от 1 до 5 в любую сторону линии нашего поля.

Такие игровые поля будут разные, можно их создать и руками, расставляя объекты на сцене с триггерами (хотя не ясно как тогда управлять игроками), а можно генерировать (вот тут тоже не понятно как, здесь нет такой зависимости как в шахматном или гекс полях).

Посоветуйте, что мне нужно найти, в какую сторону копать вообще?..

Comment: А что именно не понятно, как построить модель игрового поля или как это потом рисовать? С моделью могу помочь, а с рисованием увы, про юнити пока знаю что он есть и что на нем можно делать игры...

Comment: Как построить логику ходов верно... а критерии того что является верным, а что не верным нам самим придумать? И какие задачи эти правила должны обслуживать тоже? К чему игрок стремится, а что избегает?

Comment: согласен ничего не понятно, в каком конкретно моменте проблема?\